# xquery transformation creates empty namespace in element

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, xquery

I'm sorry but I guess I just don't see the mistake I'm making here.
I have a camel route which returns an XML and to be able to test the output I wrote a JUnit Test which runs with SpringRunner. There I get the XML Stream from the exchange which I validate against an XSD. This works great because the XSD throws an exception because the output XML is not valid, but I don't understand why the following xquery generates an element with EMPTY NAMESPACE?
See the xquery snippet (I'm sorry again I cannot provide more code):

```
declare default element namespace "http://www.dppgroup.com/XXXPMS";
let $cmmdoc := $doc/*:cmmdoc
, $partner := $doc/*:cmmdoc/*:information/*:partner_gruppe/*:partner
, $sequence:= fn:substring($cmmdoc/@unifier,3)
 return <ClientMMS xmlns:infra="http://www.dppgroup.com/InfraNS">
{
    for $x in $partner
    where $x[@partnerStatusCode = " "]
    return
    element {"DataGroup" } {
             <Client sequenceNumber="{$sequence}" />
    }
}
```

My problem is, that with this code the resulting XML contains the DataGroup-element with the following namespace definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClientMMS xmlns="http://www.dppgroup.com/XXXPMS"
           xmlns:infra="http://www.dppgroup.com/InfraNS">
   <DataGroup xmlns="">
      <Client sequenceNumber="170908065609671475"/> 
   </DataGroup>
 </ClientMMS>
```

The snippet from the Unit-Test: I'm using jdk1.8_102

```
    String xml = TestDataReader.readXML("/input/info/info_in.xml", PROJECT_ENCODING);
    quelle.sendBody(xml);

    boolean valid = false;
    try {
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) archiv.getExchanges().get(1).getIn().getBody());
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(byteArrayInputStream);

        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);

        transformer.transform(source, result);
        String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
        System.out.println(xmlString);
```

In no XQuery introduction/tutorial/explanation I can find a reason why this happens. **Can you guys please explain why the DataGroup element is not in the default namespace?**

Comment: When I try to reduce your XQuery to a minimal, self contained, executable example and execute it with Saxon or Altova the result does not have the undeclaration `xmlns=""` of the namespace. So which XQuery implementation do you use? I am also not sure how your Java code is related but in general I would try to make sure you use a namespace aware document builder instead of the default, not namespace aware one so set `setNamespaceAware(true)` on the factory before creating the DocumentBuilder.

Comment: Hi, you rock! The #setNamespaceAware(true) was missing. That's why I added the javacode too, because in the Oxygen XML Developer the problem did not occur, but only when I used the JAVA code. But because I was not sure if the difference was not there I didn't mention it :-). If you want me to give you a deserved upvote and mark your comment as solution please create an answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XQuery you posted should create the result fine without the namespace undeclaration you show.

In your Java code if you want to work with XML with namespaces make sure you use a namespace aware DocumentBuilder, as the default DocumentBuilderFactory is not namespace aware make sure you set `setNamespaceAware(true)` on the factory before creating a DocumentBuilder with it.